# Failing hardware - Tips to diagnose

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply

I recently got a new Gigabyte 7870 video card a little over a month ago. Last week I had turned my PC off for the weekend and when I turned it back on on Monday, the video card did not power on with it. I noticed the fans on the video card would spin but immediately die when the power button was pressed. Here's a quick rundown of my hardware

- Power Supply:Antec CP-850 (850w)
- Motherboard: ASUS M5A47
- Video card: Gigabyte 7870

Initially I thought it was my video card. I petitioned for a RMA from Gigabyte and at the end of the week (yesterday) I heard back. I decided to try to turn on my pc one last time just to see if miracles could happen. It decided to boot up completely. I kept it on for at least 5 or 6 hours without any issue.

I turned it off that night, and the following morning I ran into the same issue, so I decided to put in my old video card to see if it was the card. My old video card (GTX 260) also did not power on. I cleared the CMOS settings on my motherboard but that didn't make a difference. I put my new card back in and tried to turn it on several times. It booted once out of about 20 times, and it shut off on its own before it got past the BIOS splash screen.

Something else I have noticed..usually when the graphics card ends up working, it doesn't turn on right away. As I mentioned earlier, the fans spin up briefly and then die every time, but sometimes after a few seconds, it will kick up again and start. This most recent time it managed to start, It suffered an error while loading the OS. Windows 8 ran its automatic recovery/diagnostic but didn't find anything, but tried a system restore to no avail. During this whole time, my system was rebooting itself and every time the video card was able to start again (I reckon because the pc never completely turned off - just rebooted).

Now I'm thinking it could either be my PSU or my motherboard. My PSU is pretty old...it's pushing 5-6 years now I think. I know over time PSUs lose some power output and was wondering what kind of tests I might be able to perform to narrow this down between a PSU or a motherboard problem. The motherboard is less than a year old, so I could replace that under warranty still, but at the same time I'm pretty sure it must be my old PSU on it's last limb. Please advise!

I used a multi-meter to test out my PSU and it looks good. I was reading the proper voltages on the 6 pins and the 24 pin. 
Now I didn't notice this at first, because since my hard drive was always in the way of it I didn't even think of it, but I also have a second PCIe slot, but one that runs in 4x mode. I put my graphics card into the slot and hooked everything back up. It turned on every time! The fans, at least..The display however refused to turn on. I didn't get any beeps when this happened and I tested it with two video cards. They both would turn on, but the display would not turn on with it. Would this indicate the problem is likely with a faulty board?

Comment: All you can do is try things.  The PSU is the easiest thing to swap, and it does seem like a power issue.

Comment: I understand. I was hoping to hold off on a power supply for awhile, but at the same time going through the RMA process would take a couple weeks. I was hoping to get some sort of definitive evidence that would point to the hardware having the issue. I'll see if I can get a multimeter to test out the power supply tomorrow.

Comment: Updated with latest findings